# Visual Studio 2010 batch build fails

Tags: visual-studio-2010, compilation, batch-build

I have some projects I am converting from VS2008 to 2010.

But when converting them, I noticed that when doing batch builds of them, they fail to compile. The errors are

```
"unresolved external symbol: __SomeFunction".
```

__SomeFunction is from project A that compile perfectly, and the errors are happening in project B, that depends on project A.

The Build order and project dependencies are correctly set.

They compile well if I do one-by-one the configs and platforms, but this is very annoying when I have people saying to me that it is required they batch build correctly.

Side Note: I have configurations for the platforms Win32 and x64.

Help me please,

Sérgio

Answer (score 2):

Sadly this is apparently a known bug in VS2010. I just got bit myself.

See: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/556158/batch-build-links-to-wrong-referenced-projects
and
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/554339/visual-studio-2010-bug-in-platformname-handling-in-batch-build

Comment: Same. Even asked a question on SO, then eventually stumbled on those known bug descriptions.

Comment: "not found" for both links. Batch build is not working here, too, but everything is "ANY CPU".

Comment: It's been fixed in VS2012, so at least there's that.

Comment: This also happened in Visual Studio 2017 and the solution was ... COF COF COF ... installing its updates!