# visual studio 2019 - libusb - batch build fails

Tags: c++, visual-studio, build, visual-studio-2019

I'm building https://github.com/libusb/libusb on Windows 10.

I opened the `.sln` in VS 2019.

When I do a `Batch Build` and select all non-ARM targets, I get linking errors

```
Build started...
------ Build started: Project: dpfp, Configuration: Debug-MT Win32 ------
dpfp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _libusb_init_context@12 referenced in function _main
dpfp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _libusb_exit@4 referenced in function _main
dpfp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _libusb_strerror@4 referenced in function _main
```

But then if I click on that same project `dpfp` and build or re-build, it works fine

```
Rebuild started...
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: libusb_static, Configuration: Debug-MT Win32 ------
1>core.c
1>descriptor.c
1>events_windows.c
1>hotplug.c
1>io.c
1>strerror.c
1>sync.c
1>threads_windows.c
1>windows_common.c
1>windows_usbdk.c
1>windows_winusb.c
1>libusb_static.vcxproj -> C:\work\Continuum\libusb\build\v142\Win32\Debug-MT\lib\libusb-1.0.lib
2>------ Rebuild All started: Project: dpfp, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
2>dpfp.c
2>dpfp.vcxproj -> C:\work\Continuum\libusb\build\v142\Win32\Debug\dpfp.exe
========== Rebuild All: 2 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

**QUESTION**
Is this a bug in VS 2019 or something wrong with configuration of the `libusb` VS `.sln`?

I found this question but this is for VS 2010; is it possible the bug still isn't fixed?

[Visual Studio 2010 batch build fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7646062/visual-studio-2010-batch-build-fails)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduced your problem in VS2019. In Visual Studio 2022, the dpfp project batch build  successfully. But there is a project fxload batch build that fails. Currently, batch build of VS2022 still has [problems](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/build-issues-with-multiple-configuration/1654460). And you can report to the [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/cpp/report).